# Regex for strings with even number of 1's and number of 0's divisible by 5

Tags: regular-expressions

I was trying to build up this regex but I am having huge expressions but nothing generates the given regex. I tried to break up the regex as

1. $0$ multiple of five times and odd $1$'s
2. $0$ multiple of five times and even $1$'s

Bu this doesn't help me.
The regex  I Found was  $(00)^*1(00)^*1(00)^*1(00)^*1(00)^*$. But in this way two $1$'s and five $0$'s cannot be generated.
Again $(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*$ does not generate $5n$ times $0$'s for $n\ge 2$.
There are other possibilities and that too do not meet the regex.

Any help would be appreciated.

**P.s: I am at the very beginning in regex. So I am currently trying to avoid the method of conversion from finite automata to regular expressions.**

Comment: There is a problem with both regex, since $0$'s (resp $1$'s) are not necessarilly coming in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Your last idea is good, but insufficient. Also there is not the right number of zeros. Now let's try to decompose the problem:

Let's consider $L_0=\{1^i01^j01^k01^l01^m01^n,i+j+k+l+m+n \text{ is even}\}$.

Your (corrected) idea was $e_1 = (11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*$, but this only generate words of $L_0$ where $i, j, k, l, m, n$ are all even. You need now to consider other possibilities. For example, if $j$ and $m$ are odd and the rest are even, we get the regular expression:
$$(11)^*0(11)^*10(11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*10(11)^*$$
There are a total of $\binom{6}{0} + \binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{6} = 32$ expressions to consider all possibilities (choice of an even number of indices that are odd among the 6).

The final regular expression will then be $\left(e_1+e_2+…+e_{32}\right)$.

Now you need to do the same thing with a language $L_1$ containg an odd number of $1$'s, and construct the regular expression for your language with both $L_0$ and $L_1$.

This sure is ugly as hell, but hey, it works! There may be a simpler way to write it, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: The professor who wrote that exercise did not like their students!

Comment: @HendrikJan That thing is annoying, especially when beginning to learn regular expressions. (Also you didn't have to delete your answer)

Comment: @Nathaniel Still $L_0$ and $L_1$ do not meet the required regex. Bcz what you did was for $5$ number of $0$'s. But we need multiple of $5$ $0$'s. I don't know how the author found this problem but he should give a hint or at least the correct answer as hint.

Comment: @ManjoyDas As I have said, you have to use $L_0$ and $L_1$ to construct a regular expression for your language, I never stated that they are the answer. I think my answer contains enough details for you to finish it, don't you think? (Otherwise you wouldn't search it at all).

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm not blaming you or not kind of trying to demean you. What i wanted to say is that this process seems to be never ending and how many expressions you add to it, it won't be suffice to express the regex.

Comment: It will end, using Kleene star with $L_0$ and $L_1$.